# How to use route parameter as argument for a service method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-routing, angular-services

I'm trying to get product details to the route of single product.
for now 
I have route for single product with id parameter and it's working fine

```
{ path: 'single-product/:id', component: SingleProductComponent }
```

and in component typescript :

```
 id: string;
 private mainSub: any;
 public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mainSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.id = params['id'];
  }
   this.productsService
    .all()
    .map(res => res.filter(item => item.id === this.id))
    .subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));      
 });
 }
```

in the console I got the right product but How can I get data to the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

Lets encapsulate that filter logic in the service class:

```
export interface Product {
 // define the properties for your product
}

@Inject()
export class ProductService {
 ....
 // constructor injetction and other methods
 ....

 all(): Observable<Product[]>{
   // implementation
 }

 getById(id:string): Observable<Product> {
   // or maybe could your backend offer an endpoint that does this for you?
   // something like `root/api/products/:id`;
   return this.all().map(products => products.find(product => product.id === id));
 }
}
```

Now we can go back to the component:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'; // Maybe replace with lettable operators

@Component({...})
export class FooComponent {
 product$: Observable<Product>;
 constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _productService: ProductService){
    this.product$ = _route.paramMap
       .map(params => params.get('id')) // maps the route params. map to the id key
       .switchMap(id => _productService.getById(id));// change the main stream to the stream returned by the service
 }
}
```

Now in your template you could use a little trick to access to the latest value in the `product$` stream:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="product$ | async as product">
   {{ product | json }}
   // your template goes here
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to implement in your component:

```
 id: string;
 product: any;
 private mainSub: any;
 public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mainSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     // I used + sign if id is number otherwise remove it
     this.id = +params['id'];
     this.productsService
      .all()
      .map(res => res.find(item => item.id === this.id))
      .subscribe(resp => this.product = resp);      
    });
  }
 }
```

Now use your data in your html template like this (dummy html):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I already did that but got error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Can you paste your response here.

Comment: console.log response is array

Comment: actually find worked but why got error in the console while it's get the data

Comment: Can you comment error here which logged on browser console . The code is fine may be have some issue in service.

Comment: it's same error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
however it;s get the data.

Comment: I think you were used someWhere product.name. Your json object don't have name property but still you are  using somewhere in your service or component or HTML.

Comment: it's allways give error with first one.  I mean if I use {{ product.price }} then {{ product.name }}  both of them will get the data but in the console I got error for price

Comment: Can your paste your html code here and also response object of server. We should never ignore any error. It will log on console and will an eye catch if user will press f12.

Comment: for example <h3>{{ singleProduct.name }}</h3> <h5> {{ singleProduct.price }}
Response :
Product {id: "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f", name: "name", description: "desc", price: 20}

Comment: avoid nested subscribes, thats an anti pattern